# Is there an alternative to apache's END flag in RewriteRule?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have this simple .htaccess in my app's root:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

I want to remove the `RewriteCond` line so that the requests would always be rewrited, even if the request uri is `/index.php/foo/bar` for instance. I think it would go like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [END]
```

The `END` flag is necessary so the server won't go into an eternal loop. The thing is my Apache (2.22.22 -wamp) doesn't support this flag (only 2.3.9 and further). I could get an updated server or something, but I want to make sure my app doesn't brake on older servers too. What can i do here?

Comment: But wouldn't this lead to urls like `/index.php/index.php/foo/bar`? Doesn't makes sense I guess ^^

Comment: Yes, i want that to be allowed. It's very unlikely that i need this, but let's say I have some route in my App that takes a filename argument...so I want to make sure "index.php" would still be an option.

Comment: In my experience it is quite unlikely, that some code suddenly wants to make use of the filename. Even further: Usually an application shouldn't need to to take care how it was called. Just want to mention, that it seems, that you over-complicate things ^^

Comment: Pre-mature optimization is the root of all evil. And even though this may not seem like optimization to you, it surely adds complexity where it's unnecessary. Deal with this _if_ you get here. But as @KingCrunch said, you probably won't

Comment: Deleted my answer. Not even sure what you're looking for. If you want want to change the information in the URL, then why are you rewriting at all? `/index.php/index.php/asdf/asfd/asdf/asdf` will load `/index.php` without any rewrites.

Comment: I wanted to redirect every request to `index.php/[request]`, so it seemed to me like a logical mistake that I wasn't redirecting `/index.php` itself. And yes, I know about the performance damage for static files. Well...it probably won't hurt if I can't get it done, but it would be best.

Comment: Actually the main reason I want this is because `/foo/bar` should give me a page, while `/index.php/foo/bar` should show me an `404 error`.